# how to sum the maximum value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT 
       DISTINCT(ecode_id)
      ,MAX(eligible_allowance)AS monthlyBudgetAmt
      ,approval_date
    FROM vefm_dailybudget
    WHERE
        division=1 AND region=1
        AND unit=1 AND common_status IN('Finance - II Approved','Cash Disbursement')
        AND eligible_allowance != 0
        AND approval_date BETWEEN ' 2019-02-01'
        AND '2019-02-28' AND budget_type='monthly'
    GROUP BY ecode_id ORDER BY ecode_id
```

below is the value I got from above query total 91 rows. instead of 91 rows i want to display the total sum value of eligible allowance. can anyone help please

```
Ecode ID Eligible Allowance Approval Date
E2404   12000   2019-02-14
E2660   9000    2019-02-19
E2694   10500   2019-02-14
E2739   7500    2019-02-14
E2911   7500    2019-02-14
E2912   7500    2019-02-14
E2929   7500    2019-02-14
E2967   7500    2019-02-14
E3013   7500    2019-02-14
E3100   6000    2019-02-14
E3168   7500    2019-02-14
E3199   7500    2019-02-14
E3225   7500    2019-02-27
E3301   6000    2019-02-14
E3441   6000    2019-02-14
E3451   6000    2019-02-14
E3548   6000    2019-02-22
E3581   6000    2019-02-14
E3602   6000    2019-02-22
E3647   7500    2019-02-02
E3650   6000    2019-02-14
E3684   6000    2019-02-14
E3698   7500    2019-02-14
E3701   6000    2019-02-27
E3703   7500    2019-02-14
```

i need the sum value of above query is 516000

Comment: `DISTINCT(ecode_id)` DISTINCT is a keyword not a function, also in this case it is redundant, so you can remove it.. Also it looks like you are using GROUP BY [invalid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) . The query is only correct if `approval_date` column is functionally dependent from `ecode_id` column.. Can you post a table structure? `SHOW CREATE TABLE vefm_dailybudget`

Answer (score 1):

You need to sum over `monthlyBudgetAmt` your query:

```
SELECT SUM(t.monthlyBudgetAmt) AS total FROM (
    SELECT 
      MAX(eligible_allowance) AS monthlyBudgetAmt
    FROM vefm_dailybudget
    WHERE
        division=1 AND region=1
        AND unit=1 AND common_status IN('Finance - II Approved','Cash Disbursement')
        AND eligible_allowance != 0
        AND approval_date BETWEEN '2019-02-01'
        AND '2019-02-28' AND budget_type='monthly'
    GROUP BY ecode_id
) t
```

Comment: *below is the value I got from above query total 91 rows* so the OP gets 91 rows. Now  what is needed (I think) is to sum the results.  *GROUP BY handling is wrong* yes it is. But somehow the OP got these results.

Comment: *"GROUP BY handling is wrong yes it is. But somehow the OP got these results. "* indeed @SRV simply use `SELECT SUM(t.monthlyBudgetAmt) AS total FROM (SELECT MAX(eligible_allowance) AS monthlyBudgetAmt FROM vefm_dailybudget` as update on this answer you don't have to select `DISTINCT(ecode_id)` and the invalid non grouped column `approval_date`